# Solidity function with array.push() not work when structure have more than two parameters

Tags: javascript, solidity, go-ethereum, metamask, remix

I have deployed a contract with following push function to my local privatechain via remix.

```
struct TestComplex{
    address testValue;
    address delegate;
    uint testInt;
}
TestComplex[] testArray;
function setTestArrayByPush( address _delegate, address _testAddr, uint _testInt) public {
    testArray.push(TestComplex( {
       testValue:_testAddr,
       delegate: _delegate,
       testInt: _testInt
    } ));
}
```

If I call it via web3Provider@remix, it works fine, but when I call it via geth console or via JS script `contractInstance.setTestArrayByPush(<Add1>, <Add2>,<Int>)`, it will not push any thing into the array.
When I remove one attribute from TestComplex structure and the function changed as following. It works for both geth and remix.

```
function setTestArrayByPush(address _testAddr, uint _testInt) public {
    testArray.push(TestComplex( {
       testValue:_testAddr,
       testInt: _testInt
       }));
    {
}
```

So I'm wondering that what is the difference between remix function call and geth console? And how could I pass more then two parameters into stuct array in my Dapp?

Comment: Include the transaction object in your JS: `contractInstance.setTestArrayByPush(<Add1>, <Add2>,<Int>,{from: <FROM_ADDR>, gas: <GAS_LIMIT>})`. If that doesn't solve it, post the code that shows you creating `contractInstance` along with the `struct` and `testArray` portion of your contract.

Comment: @AdamKipnis Thank you for the information! the submitting works fine after pass the additional json with gas cost, Thank you very much!

Comment: @AdamKipnis One question here: how to put {from: , gas:} in python code?

Comment: @AdamKipnis I tried web3.py and it works same as web3 did

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


contract Test  {

struct TestComplex{
address testValue;
address delegate;
uint testInt;
}

TestComplex[] public  testArray;


 function setTestArrayByPush( address _testValue, address _delegate, uint _testInt) public {
testArray.push(TestComplex(
   _testValue,
   _delegate,
   _testInt
) );
}

function getTestComplex () public view returns ( TestComplex[] memory)  {
return testArray ;
}
```